# Need to run Qbasic in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to emulate Windows XP in Windows 7? I would like to run Qbasic programs on my Windows 7 laptop.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than load a whole windows VM could also try DOSBox, it's been reported to run QBasic fine.

I don't know what you're running in QBasic of course but I'd be interested to know whether you could build it with Microsoft Small Basic

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Microsoft distributes [Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) for Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate editions. It's free and you can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The QB64 IDE is QB compatible and is free at www.qb64.net and will compile 32-bit applications written in QB. It also supports Microsoft libraries and can cross-platform to Linux and MacOSx.